# Two nameserver questions

Tags: domain-name-system

1. In Godaddy's Zone File Editor, I can edit A/CNAME etc. including NS record. I am wondering if I change NS to another Nameserver, will my records, like A/CNAME, be deleted right away?
2. If I have more than two dns records, and they are mixed by different DNS servers, 
   for example,
   ns1.abc.com
   ns2.abc.com
   ns1.efg.com
   ns2.efg.com
   will that cause any issue?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Depends on how Godaddy handles that. I know from other ISPs that they keep the records in their database for later reactivation. Nervertheless, the saved records do no longer apply if you change the NS responsible for your domain (they may still apply for the TTL you have set though because the records may be cached on other servers, routers or computers). Your new NS is the responsible NS for your domain then and onle the new one is authorized to answer to DNS requests for your domain.
2. what do you mean? Having 3 records and saving them on a separate DNS server or maintain different record sets on each DNS server?
   You can answer this question to yourelf: when a client has to determine the IP for a domain name, it queries one of the DNS servers responsible for that domain name. It then receives the records which the DNS server has in its store. Depending on which server was queried the client may be directed to different hosts.

Answer (score 1):

1:  The timeframe in which they are deleted depends on the hosting provided and likely should be directed to their support.  It all depends on how they configure their nameservers.

2:  This depends on if all 4 namesevers have the same records.  If they all have the same records, this should not pose any issue.  Issues would only occur if you have different records on the various namesevers causing them to direct traffic to different locations.